# found this sample code tried to run it but it did not work

Tags: python

```
my_favorite_numbers = [4, 8, 15, 16, 42]

for number in my_favorite_numbers:
  my_favorite_numbers.append(1)
```

THE COMPILER IS NOT SHOWING ANY RESULTS I TRIED TO USE CMD , PYCHARM,SUBLIME AND AN ONLINE ONE TOO

Comment: Don't use all capitals. It is considered rude.

Comment: add `print(my_favourite_numbers)` to the end of the file

Comment: This code is very bad - it changes the list while it iterates over it and enters an infinite loop. What are you trying to do?

Comment: There are no `print` statements so there will not be any output.

Comment: don't change the list while iterating. `my_favorite_numbers = my_favorite_numbers + [1] * len(my_favorite_numbers)`?

Comment: Hi! What are you trying to acheive with this program?

Comment: This code is an infinite loop, it will never end. The list gets infinitely long since you keep appending `1` to the end of the list and will never be able to iterate over the whole list. The program will only end when you make it stop or your computer breaks.

Comment: No need to scream at us.

Comment: @QiuYU, sorry mate , i didnt know that . and  i printed the code it printed "none" in a loop

Comment: @MatthewHegarty bro i did it it printed none in a loop

Comment: @DrAmitKumar for documentation purposes accept the answer that helped you the most or provide your feedback regarding the answers provided.

Answer (score 1):

add print function in your code

```
print(my_favourite_numbers)
```

and you can check [python official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html)

Comment: The code is an infinite loop, the print statement at the end will not do anything as it is never executed.

Comment: It is like putting a print statement after a  `while 1:` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are running an **infinite** loop. I assume you need something like that:

```
my_favorite_numbers = [4, 8, 15, 16, 42]

for number in range(len(my_favorite_numbers)):
  my_favorite_numbers.append(1)
print(my_favorite_numbers)
```

Output: `[4, 8, 15, 16, 42, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`

Although the goal of this code is still not clear to me.